# Where is the Kraken?

Tags: simpleplanes

I've heard talk that there's a giant sea monster hidden as an Easter egg in SimplePlanes.  Most people call it The Kraken although apparently it's referred to in the game files as Cthulhu.

Where is this beast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fairly good video guide can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=16XzDytWkik).  I will try to summarize the proper steps needed to find it.

1. Start up the game and fly towards the pointed rocks around the coast of the island you start around
2. Keep flying out into sea until you see two smaller islands fairly far apart from one another.  You should be on the left side of both of these islands
3. Keep flying past these islands, and eventually you should see another slightly larger island in front of you after flying past  the two smaller islands.  Head towards it

> This last island you are flying towards in step 3 is really the top of the Kraken's head.  As you get closer, the Kraken will rise out of the water, allowing you to enter inside of it.

Comment: Worth noting that this tutorial starts from the *Bandit Approach* start point on the... Something island.  Not the default start location.

Comment: @cazc_941 do you know the actual island name? I'll edit that information into the answer if you can provide it. I don't actually play the game

Comment: I'm at work, I can get it tonight.  I can do the edit too later if you like.  Thanks for the answer!